# Does breeze inheritance work with breeze-mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, breeze

Breeze supports inheritance as of 1.3.2.  The DocTest unit tests demonstrate TPH, TPT, and TPC inheritance, based on an Entity Framework server.  I am trying to create a similar data service, with similar type inheritance, e.g BankAccount as a subtype of EntityBase, but using MongoDb in the server instead of EF.  So I'm loosely following the Zza sample (except not using Angular.js).

The Zza sample does not use inheritance, and it uses a basic JSON format for its metadata.  When I fetched the metadata from the DocTest

```
http://localhost:45678/breeze/inheritance/Metadata
```

it appears to be in a different format (JSDL?), so I'm stuck with trying to come up with an equivalent JSON format.  Initially this looks like adding "abstract": "true" to my base type in the metadata and "baseType":"EntityBase" to derived types.

Is there any reason to think this won't work without EF? And any reason to prefer TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) over TPC (Table Per Class), for example?

Answer (score 0):

The Breeze client doesn't care if the backend is EF or Mongo, and inheritance is supported for  either.  What is different between Mongo and EF is that with EF we are able to extract metadata about inheritance relationships from the EF model.  This is not possible with Mongo because there is no real metadata about the model stored in the Mongo database. This means that with Mongo you have to create the metadata on the client via Breeze's metadata api.  It is completely up to you as to whether and how to create an inheritance structure in the metadata that matches what will be returned from a Mongo query.  Take a look at the http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand for more information.